# how create an ejb-jar file to deploy in Glass Fish server v3

Tags: web-services, deployment, glassfish, ejb, maven-ear-plugin

I would like to know how deploy an EJB application? that also has web services with jax-ws...
I read this link http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Beans/EJBTutorial/step5.html#Create%20the%20ejb-jar%20file but use weblogic to generated deployment descriptor... How generated the deployment descriptor to Glass Fish?... How generate a ejb-jar file?...
Thank you very much for you help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is very good article, how create enterprise application (like web-service) step by step.
Using: Eclipce IDE, Java EE 6, GlassFish AS.
[Article](http://programming.manessinger.com/tutorials/an-eclipse-glassfish-java-ee-6-tutorial/)

Here is requared deployment descriptors for GLassFish AS
[Oracle DOC](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/giida.html)

I recommend you use `maven` for your projects. `Maven` can generate all that you need

```
@see maven-jar-plugin  
@see maven-ear-plugin
```